# Disabling the second dropdown based on first dropdown angular

Tags: angular

I have two dropdowns. I want to enable the second dropdown, only if first dropdown is selected by the user. (Angular version: 6)
HTML CODE:

```
<mat-form-field>   
    <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" >     
        <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
          {{food.viewValue}}     
        </mat-option>   
    </mat-select> 
</mat-form-field> 
<mat-form-field>   
    <mat-select placeholder="Favorite Drink" [disabled]="disableSelect.value">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let drink of drinks" [value]="drink.value">
          {{drink.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>   
    </mat-select> 
</mat-form-field>
```

TS code:

```
export class DropdownexampleComponent implements OnInit {

  disableSelect = new FormControl(true); 
  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];

  drinks: Drink[] = [
    {value: 'drink-0', viewValue: 'Coke'},
    {value: 'drink-1', viewValue: 'Sprite'},
    {value: 'drink-2', viewValue: 'Fanta'}
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the check for the first select box's value in the 2nd select box's `[disabled]`.
You haven't bound your first select box's value to any variable.

Try something like this:

```
<select id="power" required [(ngModel)]="powerVal">
    <option *ngFor="let pow of powers" [value]="pow">{{pow}}</option>
</select>
<select id="morepower" required [disabled]="powerVal==''">
    <option *ngFor="let mpow of morePowers" [value]="mpow">{{mpow}}</option>
</select>
```

Working Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcfmfn